# Optimize Reads or Insert

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database

Our company has a mongodb collection of millions merchants and billions of products.

A merchant can choose to go hidden after which their products shouldn't be visible to the public.

I am wondering the best way to implement this:

1. I could update all the products of the user to have a hidden status.
2. I could update the merchant to have a hidden status and read the status of the merchant for every product request to know if to show or not.

What has been your experiences if you have encountered this dilemma or what would you suggest is the best engineering approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's the merchant who's going hidden and not individual products, you should put the status on the merchant.

So option 2 in your question.

If you haven't yet implemented 'hidden' in your db, add it to your table as NULLable with a default of FALSE. Then in your query to find products of visible merchants, you can just put `where NOT merchant.hidden OR merchant.hidden IS NULL`. That way, when you add it to your db, you don't need to update it for the millions of others merchants who are non-hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Often Mongo design depends on how you are going to access the data.

if you select a merchant then their products put the hidden field in the merchant.

If you select a sub set of products independent of the merchant you will need it in the product table.